# How to display only row border of a grid (not column) using Border()

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, border, silverlight-5.0

I am using c# in silverlight application.

I have a grid with 1 row and 3 columns.
There are 2 things that i am not able to know how to do:

**(1) I have to display the boundaries of just row (not columns, only rows). How to do that?**

Currently i have a grids like this:

```
//The p in function call below is yhe object obtained on deserialixing xml.
     private  static Grid GenerateGrid(Parameters p) 
            {
                Grid myGrid = new Grid();
                myGrid.Width = 650;       
                myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                myGrid.ShowGridLines = false;

                ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
                myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
                myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
                myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

                int totalRows = p.Parameter.Count() + p.Separator.Count();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
                {
                    myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                }               
                return (myGrid);
            }
```

Call to this function is :

```
 XmlParameterClasses.Parameters parameter = 
     (XmlParameterClasses.Parameters)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
 Grid BigGrid = GenerateGrid(parameter);
```

My try to achieve is this: (I used Border to do this, see at the end of the function)

```
        private static Grid GenerateComboBox(ViewModel.XmlParameterClasses.Parameter param, int LoopCount, Grid g) 
        { //param is the object of the class Parameter
            StackPanel sp1 = new StackPanel(); //These three stackpanels are inside the grid cell
            StackPanel sp2 = new StackPanel();
            StackPanel sp3 = new StackPanel();
            ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
            TextBlock txtblk1 = new TextBlock();
            TextBlock txtblkLabel = new TextBlock();

            ////////////////////////////////////          

            //Label Display
            txtblkLabel.Text = param.Label;
            txtblkLabel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            txtblkLabel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            txtblkLabel.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
            txtblkLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            txtblkLabel.FontSize = 15;
            txtblkLabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            txtblkLabel.Padding = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10);

            sp1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            sp1.Children.Add(txtblkLabel);
            sp1.Width = 100;
            sp1.Height = 50;
            Grid.SetRow(sp1, LoopCount);
            Grid.SetColumn(sp1, 0);
            g.Children.Add(sp1);

            foreach(var item in param.Component.Attributes.Items) {
                cb.Items.Add(item);
            }
            cb.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChanged);
            cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Count - 1;



            //For text Display
            txtblk1.Text = cb.SelectedValue.ToString() + " millions";
            txtblk1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            txtblk1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            txtblk1.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
            txtblk1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            txtblk1.FontSize = 15;
            txtblk1.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            txtblk1.Padding = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10);

            sp2.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            sp2.Children.Add(txtblk1);
            Grid.SetColumn(sp2, 2);
            Grid.SetRow(sp2, LoopCount);
            g.Children.Add(sp2);


            //For combo box display
            cb.Width = 45;
            cb.Height = 25;
            sp3.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            sp3.Children.Add(cb);
            sp3.Width = 50;
            sp3.Height = 50;

            Grid.SetColumn(sp3, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(sp3, LoopCount);
            g.Children.Add(sp3);


 ////////////Here is the Border Display ////////////////////////////
            Border rect = new Border();
            rect.Width = g.Width;
            rect.Height = g.Height;
            rect.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
            rect.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            g.Children.Add(rect);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            return (g);
        }
```

but the output obtained is like this : (It just cover the border of first cell not the other two in that row, whereas i just want one border over one row(not over the column in that row, just row boundary))
[image]
Could some one please help me in achieving this step ? **Is it possible to implement what i want trying to do?**

Note: Please note that code has to be implemented using c# only , not xaml.

Comment: @TzahMama Justthe border once. (I also want to do that as well but i have no idea how to do that, I thank you so much if you have idea for both). bUT PRIMARY IS how to have border over row.

Comment: @TzahMama why you deleted the post ? Its working . I had to tick mark it .

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by creating a grid of 1 column and rows (instead of  3*3 cell it must be 1*3 (row*column)). Then creating Border in each row and then again creating grid with 1 row and 3 columns and then creating border of this small grid.

code is:

```
            Border rect = new Border();
            rect.Width = g.Width;
            rect.Height = g.Height;
            rect.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            rect.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);        

            Grid childGrid = new Grid();
            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
            childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
            childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);
            TextBlock txtblk3 = new TextBlock();
            var border = new Border()
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray)
            };
            border.Height = 14;

            var border1 = new Border()
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
            };
            border1.Height = 14;

            Grid.SetColumnSpan(border, 3);
            Grid.SetRow(childGrid, LoopCount);
            childGrid.Children.Add(border);

            txtblk3.FontSize = 14;
            txtblk3.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

            txtblk3.Text = param.Separator[SeparatorPosition];
            Grid.SetColumn(border1, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(border1,LoopCount);
            border1.Child = txtblk3;    

            childGrid.Children.Add(border1);
            g.Children.Add(childGrid);
            return (g);
```

Where "g" has only 1 column and "LoopCount" numbers of row. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `CellPainting` event of `DataGridView` control as the code snippet below:

```
private void grid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
}
```